# Remove momentum on scrollbar in javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, touch, scrollbar

I want to remove the momentum on scrollbar. I.e. when the user is not scrolling physically. The screen stop scrolling immediately.

I'm using a Mac with touchpad.

Comment: Added tag for the fact that it is a touch interface.

Comment: It's probably some Mac thing.  Everything Apple does is all animated and bouncy..

Comment: Ktash. I'm using tinyscrollbar as the plugin, http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/. I think that the momentum is more present on the Mac than on PC

Comment: It is a serious problem, I wish that there was a way to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this only happens when you are scrolling using scrolling gestures (two finger up/down swipe)? This is a system feature and cannot be disabled via Browser features or CSS. To turn it off go to System Preferences > Trackpad and disable Scrolling "with Intertia".

[image]